# instanciar objetos y guardarlos en una lista con bucle for

Tags: python

como dije en mi anterior post, soy totalmente nuevo en el mundo de la programacion, estoy practicando con las clases y estoy intentando crear un bucle for que instancie tantos objetos como el "jugador" desee y luego todos esos objetos con sus estados, los guarde en una lista, esto es posible? os paso el codigo:

```
import json

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = input("Introduce el nombre del jugador: ")
        self.last_name = input("Introduce el apellido: ")
        self.height_cm = float(input("Introduce la altura en cms: "))
        self.weight_kg = float(input("Introduce el peso en kgs: "))
        self.haircolor = input("Introduce el color del pelo: ")

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Player: %s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def weight_to_lbs(self):
        pounds = self.weight_kg * 2.20462262
        return pounds

class BasketballPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.points = input("Introduce el numero de puntos: ")
        self.rebounds = input("Introduce el numero de rebotes: ")
        self.assists = input("Introduce el numer de asistencias")

class FootballPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.goals = input("Introduce el numero de goles: ")
        self.yellow_cards = input("Introduce el numero de tarjetas amarillas: ")
        self.red_cards = input("Introduce el numero de tarjetas rojas: ")

with open("results_list.txt", "r") as results_file:
    results_list = json.loads(results_file.read())
while True:
    opcion = input("Desea: 1)añadir un jugador? o, 2)Salir del programa?")
    if opcion == "1":
        veces=int(input("cuantos jugadores quieres añadir?"))
        for i in range(0, veces):
            jugador = FootballPlayer()
            jugador_dic = jugador.__dict__
            if jugador_dic["first_name"] not in results_list:
                results_list.append(jugador_dic)
                print("Has añadido los datos de: ", jugador_dic["first_name"], jugador_dic["last_name"])
                with open("results_list.txt", "w") as results_file:
                    results_file.write(json.dumps(results_list))
            elif:
                print(jugador_dic["first_name"], jugador_dic["last_name"] "Ya estaba en la base de datos")
    elif opcion == "2":
        break
    else:
        opcion = input("Desea: 1)añadir un jugador o,2)Salir del programa?")
```

Comment: Gracias de antemano, la idea es que dentro del while si la opcion es 1, se añada ese jugador con todas sus caracteristicas(estados de su clase) a lista_jugadores, y una vez que acabe de añadir todos esos jugadores, guardar esa lista en un archivo externo, no se si me explico y tampoco se si es posible xD.

Comment: Lo primero es trivial, simplemente instancia y agrega el objeto con `list.append` a la lista (eso si, la lista definida fuera del ciclo y la instancia y el `append` dentro del `if`, si no redfines la lista cada vez que agrega un jugador...). Lo segundo ya requiere que especifiques como pasas el estado de la clase a un json y luego al contrario... También podrías usar Pickle para serializar objetos en vez de un JSON. ¿El json tendría información de ambos tipos de jugadores o sería un json para jugadores de futbol y otro para baloncesto?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, de momento solo necesito hacerlo para una clase (por ejemplo football_player), he borrado el metodo que tenia def append y he dejado el bucle asi:

Comment: Jesus no añadas código a los comentarios, para añadir información a la pregunta (o actualizarla) usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/268781/edit) que hay debajo de ella y añade o modifica lo que quieras.

Comment: hecho! gracias, vaya paquete soy... para que no te desesperes mucho conmigo, solo llevo un mes programando y nunca en mi vida habia tocado codigo antes, asi que se bueno :)

Comment: lo que ahora no consigo, es que solo añada al jugador si ese nombe ("first_name) no esta ya en el archivo...

Comment: alguien sabe como solucionarlo??? me estoy volviendo loco jeje

Answer (score 1):

Quizá sea mejor que guardes tus objetos en un diccionario y como "clave" le des el nombre del objeto, luego simplemente ocupas un "if":

```
if nombre in dict_con_objetos.keys():
  Tu codigo...
```

Si esta en tu lista el resultado de la condición será True y entrara al "if", si no el resultado será False y no entrara.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Por favor considera desarrollar una respuesta más completa, Agrega el código para construir el diccionario y una explicación de por qué un diccionario es mejor que una lista.

Answer (score 0):

No es la solución directa a tu código, si no que planteo el siguiente ejemplo para ver el concepto de instanciar objetos variables en una lista.

```
import random

class MiClase:
    def __init__(self, color_aleatorio):
        self.mi_color = color_aleatorio

    def method1(self):
        return self.mi_color

num = input("Cuantos elementos quieres instanciar?: ")
colores = ['rojo','azul','amarillo','verde','negro','gris','marron']

list_obj = []
for n in range(int(num)):
    obj = MiClase(random.choice(colores))
    # Instancia un objeto con un elemento aleatorio de la lista colores
    list_obj.append(obj)

# #############
# Listar cada objeto con su color
for obj in list_obj:
    print("Soy el objeto {} y mi color es {}".format(id(obj), obj.method1()))

# Tambien se puede seleccionar un elemento de la lista directamente
print()
print(list_obj[2].method1())
```

> ```
> Cuantos elementos quieres instanciar?: 3
> Soy el objeto 2419832552360 y mi color es azul
> Soy el objeto 2419832552472 y mi color es gris
> Soy el objeto 2419832617392 y mi color es verde
>
> verde
> ```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero ahora tengo otro problemilla...jejeje, he modificado el codigo arriba con como lo tengo ahora, pero no consigo que me busque en el archivo si el nombre introducido esta ya o no y si esta no lo añada